# Capistrano can not read ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano for deploying my Rails app. and now I`m facing error below when I enter command`cap production deploy` :

```
 ✔ 02 deploy@82.196.13.29 0.475s
04:44 webpacker:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.5" RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.5" RAILS_ENV="production" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber )

Tasks: TOP => webpacker:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: No such file or directory - ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.5" RAILS_ENV="production" RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.5" RAILS_ENV="production" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber )
```

And this is my deploy.rb file:
    lock "~> 3.11.0"

```
set :application, "appName"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:githubusername/appName"

# Deploy to the user's home directory
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

set :default_env, { 
  'RBENV_ROOT' => '$HOME/.rbenv',
  'RBENV_VERSION' => '2.5.5',
  'RAILS_ENV' => 'production'
}

append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Only keep the last 5 releases to save disk space
set :keep_releases, 5

before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Run rake yarn:install'
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install")
      end
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:updated', 'webpacker:precompile'
```

I'm using Rails 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.5.5 in this application. I also have a file `.rbenv` in `/home/deploy/appName` and contains these variables:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=ohai
SECRET_KEY_BASE=1234567890

STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=x
STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY=y
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Ruby is installed on your production machine?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar yes. I follow this article https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04

Comment: I think the file should be called `.rbenv-vars`